# For loop to create consecutive dates

Tags: php, datetime, for-loop

I wrote a piece of code using date function `mktime()` in PHP:

```
mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"))
```

I got the desired result, but I want next five consecutive dates using for loop.

What would we be the best way of going about this?

Comment: in what form do you have your "next five dates"; what means "next" here?

Comment: "what should I do?" How about [using the search function before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) because this is a duplicate.

Comment: @SparKot Don't put tags in the title of the question; things like "PHP -" are to be removed, not added.

Comment: @meagar Yeah, that makes much sense on SO site. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `strtotime` function

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
  strtotime("+" . $i . " day");
}
```

You can also do it with custom dates:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
  strtotime("+" . $i . " day", mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y")));
}
```

Comment: <?php

for ($i=1 ; $i<=5 ; $i++)
{
$date=mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));
echo "Date is :".date("m/d/Y",$i)."<br/>" ;
}

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf(date('n j Y'),'%d %d %d',$m,$d,$y);
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    echo date('m/d/Y',mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d+$i,$y)).'<br />';
}
```

Result

```
07/01/2012
07/02/2012
07/03/2012
07/04/2012
07/05/2012
```

- [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)
- [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.